# Details of the phase margin

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

In my controls class, we're covering phase and gain margins. We're asked to increase the phase margin of a given plant to greater than 45 degrees using a lag compensator. Initially, the phase margin of the open loop is -13 degrees, as shown below:

[image: Open loop plant, gain and phase margins]

My understanding is that a lag compensator *decreases* phase angle around a given frequency. This is the filter, before and after I apply it to the plant:

[image]

So, now I have a phase margin of -45.7 degrees. Does this satisfy the original criteria of greater than 45 degrees phase margin?

As far as I know, the phase margin is a measure of safety, because crossing -180 degrees will effectively turn your negative feedback into positive feedback, making the system unstable. This tells me I should use only positive feedback, because the feedback will always be 180 degrees out of phase. But, it's not clear to me whether I was supposed to increase this phase margin somehow using only lag.

For completeness, here are the compensated and uncompensated closed loop systems:

[image]

I find it interesting that the maximum amplitudes of either of these functions also roughly correspond to their -270 degree crossings. To calculate these, I'm using MATLAB's `feedback()`, which uses negative feedback.

Clarification on whatever it is I'm doing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _Does this satisfy the original criteria of greater than 45 degrees phase margin?_  No it does not.  The phase and gain margins are computed on the assumption of negative feedback.

Comment: That may be just the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You want phase lead instead of lag. Namely in your case both closed loop systems are unstable, since you have phase increase at the resonance peak/complex conjugate poles, while it should be a decrease if they where stable. You can also test this by plotting the step responses of the closed loop systems.